# Bloquear usuario

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

necesito crear la sección bloquear usuario en una app que estoy haciendo, para eso hice lo siguiente.

1.- Agregue un nuevo campo boolean a la tabla USER

```
$table->boolean('isBlocked')->default(0);
```

2.- Luego en el controlador LoginController

```
protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only($this->username(),'password');
    return array_add($credentials, 'isBlocked', 0); 
}
```

El problema radica que tanto el usuario tenga valor 0 o 1 en el campo isBlocked, el sistema no me deja ingresar.

Comment: Que no pueda loggear si está bloqueda, al menos eso decía la información en los vídeos que ví por youtube

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eso funciona para veriones >= 5.3 y te faltaria en el modelo `User.php` poner

```
public function findForPassport($identifier) {
     return User::orWhere(‘email’, $identifier)->where('isBlocked', 0)->first();
}
```

Comment: Ya lo hice funcionar y saqué el problema, lo que tu comentas es para passport el cual tengo que implementar luego, muchas gracias por el aporte.

Comment: ¿por qué fue aceptada esta respuesta si no soluciona el problema?

Comment: Yo lo he probado con Laravel 5.8 y me da un error, así:
Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::credentials() must be an instance of App\Http\Controllers\Auth\App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request, instance of Illuminate\Http\Request given, called in ...